# Adding button next to input, horizontal form style - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a delete button next to an input.

My current code:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="form">
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-9 ">
       <span>Názov položky</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <span>Cena</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<button class="add_field_button btn btn-success btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</form>
```

Generated output:

[image]

The red button isn't on the right side of the last input.

Comment: Do you want the button to be separate from the input or joined?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid the best would be separated, with a little gap.

Comment: Just curious - Is the end goal to have the plus button add new input rows?

Comment: @cricket_007 end goal is to remove that line, the green button is here for adding new input row. (the green button is always under the rows, like in the code)

Comment: Right, the delete button removes that row. I was just asking because I think using an HTML table with 3 columns would be easier than manipulating your row of div's.

Comment: Yeah, but then I lost responsiveness and I am adding data with mobile a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of these will work. You can create some margin inside of a `input-group` so the button isn't touching the input or use the grid.

See working example Snippets.

```css
.input-group .input-group-btn.input-space {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn.input-space .btn-input {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
div.input-group .form-control.input-control {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="well">Custom Input Group</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <form role="form" method="post" id="form">
      <div class="col-sm-9 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Názov položky</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Cena</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-control"> <span class="input-group-btn input-space">
         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md btn-input"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="add_field_button btn btn-success btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="well">Grid</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <form role="form" method="post" id="form">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Názov položky</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Cena</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Odstrániť</label>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="add_field_button btn btn-success btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [input-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented) as explained on the help page.

Here the relevant code

```
    <span>Cena</span>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: OP asked for button to be separate. This is joined.

Answer (score 1):

This might break on mobile, but it looks good in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpBWqW)

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <span>Názov položky</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <span>Cena</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <button class="add_field_button btn btn-success btn-md">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```